# How is Kyousuke able to teleport Andy?

Tags: zettai-karen-children

In the anime **Zettai Karen Children: The Unlimited - Hyoubu Kyousuke**, Andy Hinomiya is an esper who negates the power of all other espers. Yuugiri cannot read his mind, Kyousuke can't hypnotize him, telekinetic attacks are ineffectual against him. So how is it possible for Kyousuke to teleport him in episode 3? They're walking away and he snaps his fingers and the entire group teleports away. Is it that Andy really isn't completely immune to ESP? Or is the teleportation a side-effect of an ESP power so it isn't negated?

To clarify the side-effect thing, You Fujiura's ESP can effect sound waves, though the ESP itself can be negated by Andy, the actual sound that the ESP creates (or deadens) can be heard by Andy (episode 2).

Comment: I haven't seen the series, hence the following question. Are the esper powers on constantly or do they have to be turned on?

Comment: @ChetterHummin Active powers aren't always on, but Andy's negate power seems to be latent, as it makes espers around him feel ill when he gets too close to them, and until it was explained to him that he had an ESP negating power, he didn't even know he had it.

Comment: Is there a distance restriction for this negation ability to work?

Comment: @ChetterHummin Don't know many details about it. It would seem so because when Andy got close to other espers, they felt ill, but Kyousuke was next to him when they all were teleported. The show is still pretty new, I thought either I missed something or this question will just have to wait until the season is over.

Comment: @ChetterHummin yes there is indeed also a area limit to his ability( which increases if he stresses/gets mad ) but as terra samson said in his answer below he indeed got his negator amulet in episode 2. which he is forced to always keep on him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andy's wearing the limiter he got in episode 2.  As long as it is active, esp powers can be used around him, such as when he was teleported right after he got it.

Answer (score 3):

That's because Andy's limiter was on when Hyoubu teleported him in episode 3. When his limiter is on, Andy's power is limited. Look here:

[image]

In fact, Andy's power could negate teleportation power too. As we saw in episode 5, Magi asked Andy to turn his limiter on, so he could teleport him.

Also, here is the position of Andy's limiter when it's on.

[image]